# How to increment a given time with a given number of minutes and associate the new time to a array list

Tags: php, arrays

I need to increment a given time with a given minutes number and and associate the time with an array list of id's. An example of what I need :

```
$ids_arrays = array(699926900040821, 699926900040822, 699926900040823); 
$given_time='20:30'; 
$given_minutes = '5';
$newarray=array();
```

And I want to create a new array like this :

```
Array (
        [699926900040821] => '20:35'
        [699926900040822] => '20:40'
        [699926900040822] => '20:45' 
      )
```

My code :

```
//$_GET['grupuri']= simple array ,$ids_arrays;
//$_GET['numar_grup']=  number of minutes to increment ;
//$_GET['time_grup']=time array;
$ora_grup=array();
$h1=new DateTime($_GET['time_grup']);
$m1=new DateInterval('PT'.$_GET['numar_grup'].'M');
for ( $i=0; $h=$h1;  $h->format('H') <10;   $i <count($_GET['grupuri']) ;   $i++, $h->add($m1)) {    
    $ora_grup[$_GET['grupuri'][$i]]=$h->format("H:i\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ids_arrays = array('699926900040821', '699926900040822', '699926900040823'); 
$given_time = '20:30'; 
$given_minutes = '5';

$t = strtotime('today '. $given_time);
$newarray = array();
foreach ($ids_arrays as $id) {
    $newarray[$id] = date('H:i:s', $t += $given_minutes * 60);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This would do:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
function associateIdsWithTime(
    array $ids, 
    DateTime $startTime, 
    DateInterval $interval
) {
    $associatedIds = array();

    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $associatedIds[$id] = $startTime->add($interval)->format('H:i');
    }

    return $associatedIds;
}
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
$associatedIds = associateIdsWithTime(
    array(699926900040821, 699926900040822, 699926900040823),
    DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $given_time),
    DateInterval::createFromDateString("+ $given_minutes minutes")
);
```

For `$given_time = 20:30` and `$given_minutes = 5` it will return:

```
Array
(
    [699926900040821] => 20:35
    [699926900040822] => 20:40
    [699926900040823] => 20:45
)
```

On a side note: take caution with your ids on 32bit systems. You are using integers but `PHP_INT_MAX` on 32bit systems is limited to 2.147.483.647, which cannot fit your 699.926.900.040.822. You might want to change to strings to keep it portable.